# Multiple Key Value Pair Maps in Grails

Tags: grails, dictionary

I'm trying to dynamically populate a map based off a list of objects in Grails. Let's say I have something of the sort...

```
def criteria = Object.createCriteria()
def listResults = criteria.list() {
 -- query statements --
}

def objMap = [:]
for each(object in listResults) {
-- assign object property and object id into map -- 
}
```

So what I'm looking for is an id, property pair entry in the map. Something like:

```
[id:1, name:'Name']
```

I also need a list of such pairs. How would I do this? Thanks in advanced!!!

Comment: what would your key be in the map?

Comment: Well I guess I don't need one I'm looking for a way to create a list of two properties of an object. Say if it's a list of "Car" objects I want to populate a map (or any other collection that's appropriate for the job) that will contain multiple entries for each Car object in the list. Something like: [carName: 'Taurus', carId: 1], [carName: 'Taurus', carId:1], [carName: 'Focus', carId:2] and so forth.

Comment: I will answer below...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on your comment above wanting some data object holding for example carName and carid:

```
... listResults has result of criteria query
def results = listResults.collect { r -> [carName: r.name, carId: r.id] }
```

will give you a list of objects so results[0].carName = name of the first car...

See http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections for more groovy collection fun.

Comment: Great that works! What if I want to know how many cars named Taurus are in the collection? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use the findAll method on any collection and pass it a closure so you can get all of the Taurus' using def t = results.findAll { car -> car.type == 'Taurus' } or count them using def x = results.count { cat -> car.type == 'Taurus' }

Comment: Collection API docs: http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html

Comment: Thanks Rick! Very Helpful! Thanks for the api docs link I was looking for that.

Comment: Retrieving the whole data set from the DB just to filter it out in memory is bad practice. Just query with the projections you need, let the DB do the work, that will consume less memory and time.